# Найти максимальный элемент в каждом столбце

Tags: c++

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int ROWS = 5;
    const int COLS = 5;

    float array[ROWS][COLS];

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            cout << (array[i][j] = rand() % 10) << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    /*for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            if (array[j][i] == 0)
                count++;
        }
    }*/

    int tempmax = array[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            if (array[j][i] > tempmax)
            {
                tempmax = array[j][i];
            }
        }
    }
    
    cout << tempmax;
```

Comment: Нет описания проблемы. Код же есть. Рекомендую привести конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.

Comment: Нужно найти максимальный элемент в столбей каждого массива, как определить что столбец заканчивается и начинается новый ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
{
    int tempmax = array[0][j];
    for (int i = 1; i < ROWS; i++)
        if (array[i][j] > tempmax)
            tempmax = array[i][j];
    cout << tempmax;
}
```

"[Вот так как-то](https://ideone.com/zBtf4I)" (с)

Comment: Вот такой вывод получается - 78579, попробовал изменить i j местами, все равно не выходит. По идее должно быть - 5 8 8 7 9

Comment: А, да, переписывая ваш код, не обратил внимание, что у вас `array[j][i]`... Исправил.

Answer (score 1):

Раз нужно найти максимум в столбце, то и  внешний цикл делайте по столбцам, в начале цикла задавая временный максимум

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < COLS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            if (array[0][j] > tempmax)
            {
                tempmax = array[0][j];
            }
        }
    } в коде это так выглядит ? Оно все равно считает максимальный элемент массива, а не отделаьного столбца

Answer (score 1):

Как написал @MBo сначала цикл по столбцам

```
int tempmax[COLS]; // максимальных значений столько, сколько столбцов
for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) // сначала цикл по столбцам
{
  tempmax[j] = array[0][j]; // первоначальное значение == первому элементу
  for (int i = 1; i < ROWS; i++)  // внутри - цикл по строкам      
  {
     if (array[i][j] > tempmax[j])
     {
        tempmax[j] = array[i][j];
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо всем огромное, вопрос закрыт. Спасибо, что помогли, для меня тежяловато было бы прийти к такому решению и записи